# Run user input code in my Kotlin apps JVM

Tags: java, kotlin, jvm

I have a simple Kotlin application that has a way to get user input. This input is a piece of code (Java or Kotlin code).

Eg: user inputs `println("Hello world")`. Currently I put this String into a `.java` file and run it with `runCommand` using `java path-to-file.java` which runs the users code in a separate JVM.

However, I'd like to instead run the piece of user input code in the same JVM my application is running in. I want to allow the user to call some predefined functions exposed by my app - in their input code.

Eg: `getMeaningOfLife()` is a global function that I would expose in the JVM that the user can use in their code. I am not worried about security and don't mind giving the user complete `reflection access?` to my apps JVM.

Sample user input:

```
fun main() {
  val meaning = getMeaningOfLife()
  printer(meaning)
}

fun printer(meaning: String) {
  println(meaning)
}
```

This would result in my Kotlin app compiling/running the users code in the same JVM. As the user wants to print the result of `getMeaningOfLife` in the console, that would happen.

I would appreciate any points on how to approach this challenge.

Comment: I'm glad you realise that security is an issue here. But to underline the danger for anyone else reading this question: any bug in the code (and all code has bugs) could give the user full and unrestricted access to the account running the program (and potentially, with the right malware, to the entire machine and any others it has access to). Now, that doesn't _necessarily_ open you up to all sorts of attacks and vulnerabilities — but it's very easy to do so unless you know exactly what you're doing. Security is subtle and hard, which is why this sort of thing is generally a Bad Idea™…

Comment: @gidds thanks for sharing. The reason security is not a concern is because this would be an open source app that run son the users device (locally). I would still appreciate any tips on approaching this problem without over engineering it :)

Comment: I think, Java can consider using bytecode dynamic compilation (like ASM), Kotlin can use Kts